# term field permission for authenticated user

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, users

I have installed the tern_fields module.

I have added a term field to the taxonomy vocabulary. The specification of that field is.

type: File
widget: image

Now when I try to upload an image for a taxonomy term, it works fine for the admin but when I try to upload an image for a taxonomy term as a site manager then it gives me the following error.

```
The selected file test.jpeg could not be uploaded. Only files with the following extensions are allowed: png|gif|jpg|jpeg.
```

Where the site manager is a user role.
and in the permissions for the site manager against the term_fields module, both check boxes are checked. administer term_fields and upload term files.

what is the problem now?

Comment: Just do what the error message tells you. Add the jpeg extension to the list of allowed file extensions.

Comment: these extensions are allowed in the field list. png/jpg/jpeg/gif. But still it displays such error.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I didn't scroll to the end of the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer of my own.

I edit the field there in the file extension I had entered like this "png, gif, jpg".

I changed it to "png gif jpg". insert the space instead of the comma and it solved my problem.